# Ansible - When condition not working with meta task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I appear to be having issues with using a when condition in a meta tag. I have tried a few variations and did some reading as well, still unsure so I thought I'd ask here as well

**Tasks**

```
- name: "This is my task"
  command: "{{ path to conda }} {{ script }}"
  register: check
  until: check is succeeded
  retries: 5
  no_log: false

- name: "End this play if the script ran successfully on 1 remote target"
  meta: end_play
  when: 
    - check is succeeded
```

**Error**

> ERROR! The conditional check 'check is succeeded' failed. The error
>   was: The failed test expects a dictionary The error appears to have
>   been in '/path/to/roles/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 3, but may be
>   elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem. The
>   offending line appears to be:
>   - name: "End this play if the script ran successfully on 1 remote target"   ^ here

**Update (sharing for the sake of completion)**

Sharing the prescribed workaround. In my use-case I essentially wanted to "try" a task on the entirety of the inventory *until* successful

Ended up using host vars. This will always attempt the task if its the 1st host in the inventory and will "look-back" at the previous host's attempt before deciding to execute it again on the next inv host.

```
# my task
- name: "Attempt this task on each host if unsuccessful"
  raw: "raw_command_here_as_remote_host_is_using_rbash"
  register: status
  when: >
    inventory_hostname == ansible_play_hosts_all[0] or
    hostvars [ ansible_play_hosts_all [ groups ['my_host_group'].index(inventory_hostname) | int - 1 ] ] ['stop_it'] == 'false'
  ignore_errors: yes
  until: status is succeeded
  retries: 1

- set_fact:
    stop_it: true
    cacheable: yes
  when: status is succeeded

- set_fact:
    stop_it: false
    cacheable: yes
  when: status is not succeeded
```

Comment: Meta does work with when. I think the "check is succeeded" is wrong. Try running when: 1==1 to see if it works.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I chose to go down another route

Comment: I've shared the workaround in my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (sharing answer for the sake of completion)**

Sharing the prescribed workaround. In my use-case I essentially wanted to "try" a task on the entirety of the inventory until successful

Ended up using host vars. This will always attempt the task if its the 1st host in the inventory and will "look-back" at the previous host's attempt before deciding to execute it again on the next inv host.

```
# my task
- name: "Attempt this task on each host if unsuccessful"
  raw: "raw_command_here_as_remote_host_is_using_rbash"
  register: status
  when: >
    inventory_hostname == ansible_play_hosts_all[0] or
    hostvars [ ansible_play_hosts_all [ groups ['my_host_group'].index(inventory_hostname) | int - 1 ] ] ['stop_it'] == 'false'
  ignore_errors: yes
  until: status is succeeded
  retries: 1

- set_fact:
    stop_it: true
    cacheable: yes
  when: status is succeeded

- set_fact:
    stop_it: false
    cacheable: yes
  when: status is not succeeded
```